# background image of div not showing up

Tags: css, image

I have two divs one above the other with background images. The background of one shows up but the other does not. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I originally had the heights of the background set at 800px but it wouldn;t scale for mobile viewing so i changed the height to auto. Now the bottom background image will not show up. 
[the site](http://www.laceandbling.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intro2 div has 0 height since you set it to auto, and therefore the background is not showing up.

Since you're floating lacebling2 and main_button2 to the right, they are removed from the natural flow of the document, and are not affecting the height of the intro2 div like the their counterparts in the lacebling div

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the content in your second div is floating so it can't set the height of parent `div`

give some value to the `div` it will work currently it is `auto`

Answer (score 0):

update the parent CSS `overflow` property to

```
.parent{ overflow:auto; }
```